# Low space On my Android

Tags: insufficient-memory, lg-optimus-one

I have a LG android and I bought a sd card because I would always end up with insufficient space. I have gone through all apps and moved to sd card when it would allow. I still have so much space on the sd card and my phone will continue to say insufficient space! I have cleared cache several times and still have tons of storage on sd card! Help!

Comment: First aid on the way: Please check our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) for background and help. We've set that up as this kind of question pops up almost daily here :)